# git log not listing commits since a certain date

Tags: git, date, git-log

I just migrated a massive amount of source history from MKS to a git repository using git fast-import. The problem is that when I use "git log" to see all commits in the repository in the last 10 days there are certain commits that are not being listed, but should. This is what I'm doing to reproduce this issue:

When I type this command to list 3 commits by author "renato":

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad" --author renato -3
```

I get the following output:

```
8cd40f6 renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:35:28 2016 -0600
a2694d2 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:30:14 2016 -0600
57ee8d3 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:08:33 2016 -0600
```

Notice the date of the first one is Feb 15, 2016 which is 5 days ago.

But if I issue the following command to list all of his commits in the last 10 days it displays nothing:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad" --author renato --since=10.days
```

I've actually played around with this a bit and I found that the value I can issue for "--since" that will work to finally show his commits is 24 years!:

```
>git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad" --author renato --since=24.years
8cd40f6 renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:35:28 2016 -0600
a2694d2 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:30:14 2016 -0600
57ee8d3 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:08:33 2016 -0600
aa0d926 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:08:08 2016 -0600
13fdca1 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:08:22 2016 -0600
32c5af7 renatoo Wed Jan 20 08:59:56 2016 -0600
68231db renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:18:55 2016 -0600
2c25c72 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:17:28 2016 -0600
1d7ddd3 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:18:08 2016 -0600
9677ed9 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:16:51 2016 -0600
1da4267 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:14:39 2016 -0600
c64b3e1 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:14:03 2016 -0600
ea9fe12 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:10:10 2016 -0600
708b712 renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:12:27 2016 -0600
b24a2cf renatoo Thu Jan 14 15:13:12 2016 -0600
15c5abe renatoo Fri Jan 29 15:32:53 2016 -0600
a698bbe renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:36:51 2016 -0600
861b322 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:29:37 2016 -0600
3da4bcf renatoo Fri Jan 29 15:32:17 2016 -0600
3a1db85 renatoo Fri Jan 29 15:32:14 2016 -0600
d60841f renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:36:17 2016 -0600
132d762 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:28:49 2016 -0600
764d6e0 renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:36:23 2016 -0600
9d35f44 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:29:10 2016 -0600
f808b8b renatoo Mon Feb 15 10:36:09 2016 -0600
2b04034 renatoo Fri Feb 5 13:28:37 2016 -0600
682a776 renatoo Mon Jan 25 11:46:30 2016 -0600
1276d4b renatoo Fri Jan 22 10:42:39 2016 -0600
ad77333 renatoo Mon Jan 25 11:47:09 2016 -0600
2df0aec renatoo Fri Jan 22 10:42:25 2016 -0600
>
```

But 23 years doesn't work:

```
>git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad" --author renato --since=23.years
>
```

I've tried a lot of different things, including looking at the committer date and the author date (they all match for these commits, in this case), as well as trying options --all, --branches, and --reflogs.

Is there a different and more reliable way to get all commits within a given timespan (I'm personally interested in commits made in the last 3 days)?
Could there be some corruption of the repo?

Edit: Fixed last example command line.

Comment: It might be interesting to see what `git rev-parse --since=10.days` prints.  Compare that with what it prints for `--since=24.years`, for instance.  (It should turn both into a `--max-age` with a number of seconds since 1970.)

Comment: '>git rev-parse --since=10.days  
--max-age=1455169600'  
  
'>git rev-parse --since=24.years  
--max-age=698651205'

Comment: Hm, those look pretty sensible.  So, still no idea why the 10.days version isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

In your case the answer is pretty simple:

```
git log --since=10.days
```

Here are some other examples which you can use.

#### `--after` or `--before`

```
# You can also pass in relative references 
# like "1 week ago" and "yesterday":    
git log --after="2014-7-1"
get log --after="yesterday"
```

#### `--since and --until`

The `--since` and `--until` flags are synonymous with `--after` and `--before`, respectively.

---

#### More samples:

```
git log --before <date>
git log --after <date>
git log --after 2.days.ago
git log --after <date> --before <date>
```

Comment: How is that the simple answer, when the entire point of the question is that they specifically tried that, and it isn't working for them?